# Merging two select queries and displaying first queries record in top

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2005, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have one query result having data in `lastName` column as below

```
Select * from department where departmentid in (1,2)

DepartmentID  LastName 
------------  --------
1,2           A
2             D
1             C
1             B
1,2           Y
```

Now I want result with ascending order by LastName but 
Whenever above query return result containing last name Y. It should come on top.
like below result set

```
LastName 
--------
Y
A
B
C
D
```

How can we achieve it through sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a conditional `order by`:

```
order by (case when LastName = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) desc,
         LastName
```

Comment: actually I want result in ascending order always but if result set include 'Y' the result set will contain Y on top and other records in ascending order.

Comment: @irshad . . . That is what this `order by` clause does.

Comment: :- Sorry I have not tried in Sql,  That's fine It is working for me.. Thanks for your help....